# Retrieve the previously checked checkboxes on page refresh using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I have an html code where the checkboxes are checked and onclick of a button the values of checkboxes are sent accross a function. When the user checks a checkbbox the corresponding chidren checkboxes are also checked. If i refresh the page I want to retrieve the previously checked checkboxes. I tried using localStorage to store the checkbox values .

```
localStorage.setItem("check", check);
```

Then in another function tried to retrieve it by doing

```
    localStorage.getItem("check");
        if(check){
        $("input[name='favorites']").attr("checked", "checked");
$(check)
        .closest('li')
        .find('input:checkbox')
            .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
}
```

But this does not work . I need to retrieve only the checkboxes which were checked previously on page refresh.

My complete code with demo

**html**

```
<ul class="test_ex">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref">Fruits</a>

        <ul class="example">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Apple </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Orange </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="test_ex_sample">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref">Birds</a>

                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Peacock </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Parrot </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" /> <a class="ref"> Food </a>

                        <ul class="example">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Bread </a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="testB" value="OK" />
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    // Clicking on an <input:checkbox> should check any children checkboxes automatically
    $('input:checkbox').change( fnTest );

    // Clicking the OK button should run submit(), pop up displays all checked boxes
    $('#testB').click( submit );
});


function fnTest(check) {
    // Set all child checkboxes to the same value
    $(check)
        .closest('li')
        .find('input:checkbox')
            .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
}

function submit(check) {
    // When you click OK, dipslay the label for each checkbox
    var checked = [];
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        checked.push( $(this).next('a').text() );
    });
    alert("You have selected:\n\n - " + checked.join("\n - ") );
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3a050r6r/2/)

Comment: FYI: ID's should be unique on the page. `id="chckBox"` should only be used once!  Try changing to classes OR, if you need to get them individually, creating unique ID's for each element.

Comment: but i am not using any classes or id to store them in localStorage 
I am just sending the value which is checked.

Comment: I didn't say you were... thus the **FYI**. If you are not using the ID then remove it!

Comment: Can you show the code with the localStorage solution? It might be as easy as `var check=localStorage.getItem("check");`

Comment: @Gary sir: this is the fiddle which demonstrates localStorage. http://jsfiddle.net/3a050r6r/2/    Run it check some checkboxes click on ok and again run it. Its giving object Object alert but not checking the boxes

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("prevChecked",$(this));`  does not work.  You are storing `[object Object]` because it is a jQuery object.  My recommendation would be to create unique data attributes for each checkbox and save that list to localstorage.  I will try to write up some example code shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this code and see if it works for you:

```
$(function() {
  // Clicking on an <input:checkbox> should check any children checkboxes automatically
  $('.ref').each(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.siblings('input').attr('data-name',$t.text());
  });

  $('input:checkbox').change( fnTest );

  // Clicking the OK button should run submit(), pop up displays all checked boxes
  $('#testB').click( submit );

  display();
});

function fnTest(e) {
  // Set all child checkboxes to the same value
  $(this)
    .closest('li')
    .find('input:checkbox')
        .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
}

function submit(check) {
  // When you click OK, dipslay the label for each checkbox
  var checked = [];
  $('input:checked').each(function() {
     checked.push( $(this).attr('data-name'));
  });
  alert("You have selected:\n\n - " + checked.join("\n - ") );
  localStorage.setItem("prevChecked",checked.join('|'));
}

function display(){
  var test=localStorage.getItem("prevChecked");
  alert(test);
  var results = test.split('|');
  for (var r=0, len=results.length; r<len; r++ ) {
    $('input[data-name="'+results[r]+'"]').prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**
See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3a050r6r/6/

Comment: sir : this link is the same as my fiddle sir

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3a050r6r/6/... This is your code. But I cant give data-name to each field as the names are dynamically generated :(

Comment: You did not specify this anywhere in your question.  I can only go by what is in the question.  Dynamically generated by what?

Comment: I dint know there will be changes in the html code. Sorry for that . Its just a tree based on some db tree is generated.

Comment: Well, the problem you are having is you are trying to store a jquery object in localStorage.  That doesn't work.  You need a string values that you can store.  You could try using the text value but it would require much more complicated jQuery to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yes sir. I read localStorage is for strings but what is the other alternative to solve my issue. Its not mandate that I should use localStorage. I am not finding other way to retrieve the prev checked checkboxes

Comment: If you use a storage solution, you will need to store a string, integer or something.   You can't directly store a DOM object that I know of.  Using your existing markup, the only unique item is the text string, so you would need to store those strings and, upon load, read them out of storage and select the appropriate checkboxs based on that.  I don't see another way to do it.  Maybe someone else can post an answer.

Comment: Updated code above.  To read the text value and programmatically add it to the input.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the localStorage to a variable while doing a get like this

```
var check = localStorage.getItem("check");
```

Edited :

```
         $(function() {
// Clicking on an <input:checkbox> should check any children checkboxes automatically
$('input:checkbox').change( fnTest );

// Clicking the OK button should run submit(), pop up displays all checked boxes
$('#testB').click( submit );

display();
    });


    function fnTest(e) {
   // Set all child checkboxes to the same value
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
     localStorage.setItem("prevChecked",$(this).attr("id"));
     localStorage.setItem("checkedState",$(this).prop('checked'));
   $(this)
    .closest('li')
    .find('input:checkbox')
        .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
 }


function submit(check) {
// When you click OK, dipslay the label for each checkbox
 var checked = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    //localStorage.setItem("prevChecked",check);
    checked.push( $(this).next('a').text() );
});
alert("You have selected:\n\n - " + checked.join("\n - ") );
}
    function display(){
     if(localStorage.getItem("checkedState")!="false")
    {
    var test=localStorage.getItem("prevChecked");
   alert(test);
    alert($("#"+test).closest('li').html());
    $("#"+test).closest('li')
    .find('input:checkbox')
        .prop('checked', localStorage.getItem("checkedState") );
        }
    }
```

Link to your updated fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/3a050r6r/36/

Comment: same results nothing changes :(

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle link above. Have updated ur code in the fiddle